# Generate new field in $project from the value of another

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of users with a field named `level` with a numeric value of 0 to 3. I am trying to return a generated field with the textual representation of the user's level. So far I have this, but it replaces the `level` field.

```
{ $project: {
                '_id': 1,
                'name': 1,
                'email': 1,
                'username': 1,
                'password': 1,
                'registered': 1,
                'level': {
                            $switch: { 
                                        branches: [
                                          { case: 0, then: 'Pending' },
                                          { case: 1, then: 'Regular' },
                                          { case: 2, then: 'User manager' },
                                          { case: 3, then: 'Administrator' }
                                        ],
                                        default: 'Unknown'
                                     }
                },

            }
```

I would like to have a field named `levelName` in my aggregation output. How do I do this? I tried this:

```
'levelName': {
            $switch: { 
                        branches: [
                          { case: { level: 0 }, then: 'Pending' },
                          { case: { level: 1 }, then: 'Regular' },
                          { case: { level: 2 }, then: 'User manager' },
                          { case: { level: 3 }, then: 'Administrator' }
                        ],
                        default: 'Unknown'
                     }
},
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Use `$eq` operator expression for equality. Something like `{ case: { "$eq": ["$level", 0] }, then: 'Pending' }..`

Comment: Point is , it's not clear what you are asking without showing a document and the expected result. You do actually need a "field comparison" to return anything, where you seem to be thinking that the operator is comparing to the field of the same name you are projecting on, but it does not. The operator is just general and needs to be told what to compare to as input.

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thanks Veeram!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In projection, you can easily change field name. For example, in your data, if you want to change your name of `level` field to `levelName`, you can simply write new name in field and assign value of old fieldName using `$fieldName`.

```
{
    $project: {
        levelName: "$level"  //new name is levelName, and is assigned value of original field name level. 
    }
}
```

Now, in your case, you can achieve this by above way, However, your `$switch` statement is invalid or you are using `$switch` in wrong way. You need to specify which field to compare in your `case expression` i.e. `{ case: {$eq:["$level", 0]}, then: 'Pending' }` instead of `{ case: 0, then: 'Pending' }.`

```
db.indexName.aggregate([
{
    $project:
    {
        '_id': 1,
        'name': 1,
        'email': 1,
        'username': 1,
        'password': 1,
        'registered': 1,
        levelName: {
            $switch: { 
                branches: [
                    { case: {$eq:["$level", 0]}, then: 'Pending' },
                    { case: {$eq:["$level", 1]}, then: 'Regular' },
                    { case: {$eq:["$level", 2]}, then: 'User manager' },
                    { case: {$eq:["$level", 3]}, then: 'Administrator' }
                ],
                default: 'Unknown'
            }
        }
    }
}   
])
```